# Confusing DES Datalog Syntax Error

Tags: database, compiler-errors, prolog, datalog

When trying to /consult a .dl file in DES Datalog, I'm getting a bizarre syntax error code which I cannot decipher.

The entered command and corresponding error message:

```
DES> /consult trike.dl 

Error: Syntax error: operator expected after expression
       File: c:/[file path]/trike.dl
       Line: 1, Column: 10
Info: 0 rules consulted.
```

The code of the .dl file:

```
/assert make(trike, wheel, 3).
/assert make(wheel, spoke, 2).
/assert make(wheel, tire, 1).
/assert make(tire, rim, 1).
/assert make(trie, tube, 1).
/assert make(trike, frame, 1).
/assert make(frame, seat, 1).
/assert make(frame, pedal, 1).
```

Comment: Try to remove all `/assert`s from the file. I think they are needed only when you assert facts from command line, not when you consult a file.

Comment: I mean instead of `/assert make(trike, wheel, 3).` just leave `make(trike, wheel, 3).`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Sergey suggested, the answer was to remove the /assert(s).